# YouTube v3 API Search etag is inconsistent

Tags: youtube-api, youtube-data-api

When using the search endpoint, I am getting one of a set of ETags for the same request, even if the content has not changed. This behaviour happens consistently and prevents me from caching the response as I do not always receive a 304 status.

Example: https://developers.google.com/youtube/v3/docs/search/list?apix=true&apix_params=%7B%22part%22%3A%5B%22snippet%22%5D%2C%22maxResults%22%3A1%2C%22order%22%3A%22viewCount%22%2C%22q%22%3A%22skateboarding%20dog%22%2C%22type%22%3A%5B%22video%22%5D%2C%22videoDefinition%22%3A%22high%22%7D

This is taken from YouTube's own [documentation](https://developers.google.com/youtube/v3/guides/implementation/search) but limited to one search result.

The response includes a random one of two ETags, these being:

```
"etag": "-729CMjUYIG2kMmgCBFB77g7ibc"
```

or

```
"etag": "P9FEgO5WTt8njOwQgoPMkE8hZdI",
```

The rest of the data, including the `etag` of the item in the `items` array is unchanged.

Comment: As unfortunate as it is, this is a known issue of the API. I'd recommend to file a complain to Google directly via its [own issue tracker](http://issuetracker.google.com/). The least that they can do is to document properly the current API behavior.

Comment: Thank you. Created an issue: https://issuetracker.google.com/u/1/issues/176760791

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This issue has since been resolved by YouTube.

Reference: https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/176760791?pli=1